# Can someone explain the root test and when to use it?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, proof-writing

Can someone dumb down and explain the root test for the convergence of a series. Also How to identify when to use it and how?

my intuition tells me to use the root test on this problem but I don't have the understanding to apply it

$$\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\Big(\frac{k+1}{2k+3}\Big)^k$$

Answer (score 2):

You need to take k-th root of sum's argument and calculate the limit:

$$L=\lim_{k \to \infty}\sqrt[k]{\left(\frac{k+1}{2k+3}\right)^k}= \lim_{k \to \infty} \frac{k+1}{2k+3}=\frac{1}{2}$$

Based on the value of $L$ we can determine if the sequence is convergent ($L<1$) or divergent ($L>1$). If the limit turns out to be equal to $1$, we cannot determine if the sequence converges and other test needs to be used.

In our case $L=\frac{1}{2}<1$, which means the sequence is convergent.

Answer (score 1):

We have that

$$\sqrt[k]{a_k}=\frac{k+1}{2k+3}=\frac{1+\frac1k}{2+\frac3k} \to \frac{1+0}{2+0}=\frac12<1$$

therefore the series converges.

As an alternative we have

$$\Big(\frac{k+1}{2k+3}\Big)^k=\frac1{2^k}\Big(\frac{2k+2}{2k+3}\Big)^k\le \frac1{2^k}$$

and conclude by direct comparison test.

Answer (score 0):

Let the index of summation be $k$.

The root test
is easy to apply,
as in your example,
when there are
expressions raised to the
$k$-th power.
Taking the
$k$-th root
just means
dividing the exponents
by $k$.

Note that if
$k$ is raised to a fixed power,
such as $k^a$,
that this will not affect
the radius of convergence,
since
$k^{a/k} \to 1$
as $k \to \infty$.
This might affect whether or not
the sum converges
at the boundaries of
the region of convergence.

If the expression
has factorials,
the ratio test might be easier
since the ratio of
consecutive terms
of an expression
involving factorials
is often easy to compute.

If you want to use
the root test
on expressions involving factorials,
just use Stirling to get

$\begin{array}\\
((ak+b)!)^{1/k}
&\approx ((\sqrt{2\pi(ak+b)}(\frac{ak+b}{e})^{ak+b})^{1/k}\\
&\to (\frac{ak+b}{e})^{a+b/k}\\
&\to (\frac{ak+b}{e})^{a}\\
&\to (\frac{ak}{e})^{a}(1+b/(ak))^{a}\\
&\to (\frac{ak}{e})^{a}\\
\end{array}
$

This, by itself,
will  diverge.
However,
there are usually
other terms involving
powers of $k$
that will cancel out
so the result
will depend on the
coefficients of
the various factorial terms.